# Convert cURL to Guzzle POST with --form-params and --header

Tags: forms, curl, parameters, header, guzzle

I'm struggling with a given curl-request which I want to handle over guzzle.

The curl-request looks like this:

```
curl --location --request POST "https://apis.myrest.com" \
  --header "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer YOUR-BEARER-TOKEN" \
  --form "mediaUrl=https://myfile.mpg" \
  --form "configuration={
    \"speechModel\": { \"language\": \"en-US\" },
    \"publish\": {
      \"callbacks\": [{        
      \"url\" : \"https://example.org/callback\"
    }]
  }
}
```

And I want it to send via guzzle like that:

```
// 1. build guzzle client:
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
$this->client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $this->config->getBaseUri(),
]);

// 2. build guzzle request:
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
$request = new Request(
    'POST',
    'myendpoint',
    [
        'authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->config->getApiToken(),
        'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
        'content-type' => 'application/json',

        // maybe here, or not?
        form_params => ['mediaUrl' => 'www.media.com'],
    ]
);

// 3. send via client
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
response = $this->client->send($request, ['timeout' => self::TIMEOUT]);
```

My problem now is, that I have no clue how to handle this. In guzzle's documentation i found "form_params":
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#making-a-request#post-form-requests

But it does not seem to work. If I add the form_params-array to my request, the receiver does not get them. Can anybody tell me, how to write the exact curl-command with guzzle?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `multipart` instead of `form_params`.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params

From Guzzle documentation:

> form_params cannot be used with the multipart option. You will need to
>   use one or the other. Use form_params for
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded requests, and multipart for
>   multipart/form-data requests.

Additionally try setting Guzzle Client with `debug` on, as it will display raw HTTP request that it sends, so you can compare it more easily with the curl command.

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug

It is difficult to understand what is the exact request you would like to send, because there is incosistencies between the curl example and your code. I tried to replicate the curl as best as I could. Please note that `Request` 3rd parameter only expects headers, and for request options you have to use the 2nd parameter of `send`.

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'https://example.org',
    'http_errors' => false
]);

$request = new Request(
    'POST',
    '/test',
    [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer 19237192837129387',
        'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ]
);

$response = $client->send($request, [
    'timeout' => 10,
    'debug' => true,
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'mediaUrl',
            'contents' => 'https://myfile.mpg'
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'configuration',
            'contents' => json_encode([
                'speechModel' => [
                    'language' => 'en-US'
                ],
                'publish' => [
                    'callbacks' =>
                        [
                            [
                                'url' => 'https://example.org/callback'
                            ]
                        ]
                ]
            ])
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Hi @ncla, and thank you very much for your response, it works! I have one further question: according to my understanding I would like to put all options into the request object. Is this possible?
To be hones I do not understand when to put which option into which object:
The Guzzle-Doc (http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html ) says, you can put every option into the client as "default request option", so why do you put the options into the "send"-method instead of the request-object?

Comment: @j0nnybrav0 you're right, it seems a bit silly. if you want to simplify things you could use `$client->post('/test', $options);` for example and then set the headers in $options instead. You can set request headers both when you create Request object and when you create $options. Request class only accepts some parameters (with 3rd being headers only). https://github.com/guzzle/psr7/blob/master/src/Request.php#L32 I used `send` methods because that's what you used. You can use `->request()` too like `$client->request('POST', '/test', $options)`.

Comment: `send()` just allows you to pass your own Request object, which allows you to customize it more. Basically `send` is more low-level method than `request`. Use `request()` if you do not want to worry about dealing with Request objects. :)

Comment: Here's how to add headers through options. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#headers It has to be within a key "headers" in options array.

Comment: Again: thank you very much! Now everything seems to be a little bit clearer.
I thought the better oop-way seems to be working with the request-object, but I think your solution is way easier to work with.